# Simple Issue in calling the class in html

Tags: javascript, css, html, cordova

I'm using two html files 01-default.html and 17-responsive.html. there are grid view images in first html page, when clicked on any images the corresponding full size images with header and footer is displayed from the second html file...

01-default.html page

```
ul id="Gallery" class="gallery">

    <li><a href='17-responsive.html#swiper-slide red-slide' ><img src="images/thumb/a.jpg" alt="Image a" width="230" height="348"/></a></li>
    <li><a href='17-responsive.html#swiper-slide blue-slide' ><img src="images/thumb/b.jpg" alt="Image b" width="230" height="348"/></a></li>
    <li><a href='17-responsive.html#swiper-slide orange-slide' ><img src="images/thumb/c.jpg" alt="Image c" width="230" height="348"/></a></li>
    </ul>   
 </div>
```

17-responsive.html page

```
 <div class="swiper-slide red-slide">
  <div >
   <img id="scream1" src="file:///android_res/drawable/a.jpg" >    
   <div class="Footer1">
 </div>
<div class="Header">
  </div>  
   </div>                        

 </div>                

        <div class="swiper-slide blue-slide">            
    <img id="scream2" src="file:///android_res/drawable/b.jpg" > 
  <div class="Footer1">
 </div>
<div class="Header">
  </div>  
   </div>           

     </div>

  <div class="swiper-slide orange-slide">
  <img id="scream3" src="file:///android_res/drawable/c.jpg" >       
           <div class="Footer1">
 </div>
<div class="Header">
  </div>  
   </div>               
     </div>
```

Here the problem is which ever image is clicked by default it displays the first image from the 17-responsive.html page. i want the entire class to be displayed with full size image, header and footer.  even changed like  still did not work out for me. please help me...

Answer (score 1):

01-default.html page

```
<ul id="Gallery" class="gallery">
    <li><a href='17-responsive.html#red-slide.swiper-slide' ><img src="images/thumb/a.jpg" alt="Image a" width="230" height="348"/></a></li>
    <li><a href='17-responsive.html#blue-slide.swiper-slide' ><img src="images/thumb/b.jpg" alt="Image b" width="230" height="348"/></a></li>
    <li><a href='17-responsive.html#orange-slide.swiper-slide' ><img src="images/thumb/c.jpg" alt="Image c" width="230" height="348"/></a></li>
</ul>
```

17-responsive.html page

```
<div class="swiper-slide" id="red-slide">
  <div >
    <img id="scream1" src="file:///android_res/drawable/a.jpg" >    
    <div class="Footer1"></div>
    <div class="Header"></div>  
  </div>                        
</div>                

<div class="swiper-slide" id="blue-slide">
   <div>    
      <img id="scream2" src="file:///android_res/drawable/b.jpg" > 
      <div class="Footer1"></div>
      <div class="Header"></div>  
   </div>           
</div>

<div class="swiper-slide" id="orange-slide">
  <div>
       <img id="scream3" src="file:///android_res/drawable/c.jpg" >       
       <div class="Footer1"></div>
       <div class="Header"></div>  
  </div>               
</div>
```

i make some changes in your code now try this.

Comment: thanks for your reply, i'm able to get header and footer on onclick of the images. but still it shows the first image not the respective images... @jignesh kheni

Comment: can you put your code in jsfiddle for better understand your problem and give you proper solution @DD.